# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, runtime-error

I am trying to install ElasticSearch. But when I launch the elasticsearch from the bin folder, I'm getting this error:

```
filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I have configured the enviroment variables as below:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20;C:\elasticsearch;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40;"
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch: filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510018/elasticsearch-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-incorrect)

Comment: Please note: just **repeating** your question when you don't receive answers is **not** a good idea. Please be patient; and wait for answers to your first questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
 this is the environment variable you should use not with bin 
and moreover every other software you use please use latest version 
mine was causing problem because i was using 1.6

Thanks again for your help 
Thanks